# Send monit alert at most once in Linux?

Tags: monit, sms

My script to send sms

```
#send-sms.sh 
curl "http://10.10.10.10:1084/somerandomhexcode&username=username@goes.here&password=passwordgOesHere&countryCode=countrycodegoeshere&mobileNumber=%2bphone_number_with_country_code_goes_here&message=message_goes_here"
```

I've tested this script independently and it sends SMS successfully.

My monit config to check if a certain glassfish domain is down:

```
check host DOMAIN_I_WANT_TO_CHECK with address 127.0.0.1
  if failed port 10080 then exec "/root/send-sms.sh"
```

`send-sms.sh` is executable with `chmod 777`.

Imagine a scenario where the server goes down at 11 PM till 5AM, and alert keeps going every 60 seconds. It'll be an absolute nightmare. How do I avoid such scenarios?